# File part of multiple installation targets not correctly deployed to device

Tags: qt, deployment, embedded, qmake

in a Qt project (qmake) there are database files that is part of a install target:

```
dbs.CONFIG += no_check_exist
dbs.path = $$OUT_PWD/../dist/DB
dbs.files = \
    $$PWD/a.sqlite \
    $$PWD/b.sqlite \
    $$PWD/c.sqlite \
    $$PWD/d.sqlite
INSTALLS += dbs
```

The project also contains a test which also has a install target:

```
testfiles.path = $$OUT_PWD/../dist/test
testfiles.files = \
    $$PWD/a.sqlite \
    $$PWD/b.sqlite 
INSTALLS += testfiles
```

What happens now is that in remote debugging QtCreator copies *a.sqlite* and *b.sqlit*e to *test* sub-folder, and *c.sqlite* and *d.sqlite* to *DB* sub-folder. It seems like the previous destination is overwritten.
What I expected is that *a.sqlite* and *b.sqlite* are also copied to DB folder.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Such problem should never arise. Try to explore the generated makefile. The relevant section is near the end of it.

Comment: Hi,
the corresponding Makefile entries exist in both Makefiles (in the Makefile from the plugin and the Makefile from the test).
I'm afraid the problem is somewhere in the QtCreator deploy mechanism (which somehow collects the file dependencies from all Makefiles)